# Firestore Project architecture

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I need some solutions to overcome query limitations. Please suggest some best practices for us.

**Method 1** : To use Elastic Search for complex queries
                 (Problem : Have to depend on one more service)

**Method 2** : Use Cloud Mongo Db for Most of Database, only specify realtime neccessery data in Firestore.

**Method 3** : Use only Mongo Db and work ourself realtime and other features. 
                 (Problem : Have to consider replicas,auto scaling feature )

Can you suggest any other methods, to overcome query limitations or best workaround practices to use `firestore`.

Comment: What do you mean by query limitation? Query performance, scalability, quota (cost), query document/collection, searching field issue?

Comment: Limitations in complex queries, like I cannot use not in where, cannot search case insensitive, complex aggregation like MongoDb, etc. I have to do work around for everythings.